# How do i mention my work experience in my resume from multiple domains

Tags: software-industry, resume, job-change, work-experience

I need suggestions on mentioning about my technical writing experience in my resume.

I have total of 4+ years of experience in Software industry in **Company A** as a programmer and I was also responsible for preparing technical documents for about 2 years for in-house(internal) projects.

Now in my current **company B**, I am a professional technical writer, with around 6 months of experience.

I have decided to continue my career into technical writing.

This is what i have mentioned in my resume-

`Innovative technical writer with 2+ years of technical writing experience`.

2+ years is from - my previous company's inhouse writing experience and 6 months - from my current company experience.

The problem is that my Company A's designation was a Senior Software Engineer.

And in Company B - designation is Technical Writer.

How do i correctly mention this is my resume, as there is a domain change and also designation difference.

Kindly suggest your inputs.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I list skills on my résumé if I have no interest in using them again?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19625/should-i-list-skills-on-my-r%c3%a9sum%c3%a9-if-i-have-no-interest-in-using-them-again)

Comment: Yes that link is fine though, my question was to suggest on framing the sentence for my scenario and also i cannot change the designation in my resume from my Company A. So how do i include this in my resume?

Comment: If this is a word setting questions, may I suggest that the Writing Exchange would be a better place for this???

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you are allowed some bullet points in a resume. "Software Engineer" is quite broad and can be anything from IT support with some coding to scientist developing and implementing new things in software. So some points that further explain your exact roles and also include your achievements in this role should be fine.

For example, something like

**Senior Software Engineer at X Company**

- developed and implemented software solutions for in house projects, using c++, java script and 20 other cool programing languages
- wrote (whatever you wrote, make it sound cool)
- lead a team of 5 developers, implemented SCRUM and daily table soccer tournaments

Depending on the job you are applying for, change the points to match the skills and experience they are looking for.

Comment: This is a great answer. I would emphasize - don't be tempted to alter your titles, just list them as according to your official title at that employer. Then use bullets to focus on the relevant material.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk, appreciate your suggestion. Currently i have mentioned almost like this.. with the designation as "Senior Software Engineer" and in points have mentioned more about my contribution towards writing and stuff.. so just wanted to know if there was any other better way of putting this in resume. Also my confusion was, how to specify the overall experience in Tech writing, as i had 4 years into software and almost a year into writing?