# Should I put C, C++, Java and Python projects in my resume if I want to go into web development?

Tags: resume, career-development

I have been learning C, C++, Java and Python but I want to go into web development and I will soon start learning its languages and technologies. Would it be useful to put projects made in the above languages on my resume or should I only put projects related to web development?

Comment: What reasons could you come up with yourself why you should or should not display them? Furthermore, what kind of webdeveloper would you like to be? Frontend (UI/UX) or backend or both?

Comment: @WG- I want to become a full stack developer. Displaying projects of the above languages might look good on my resume but I am also confused because it wouldn't add to my web development profile and would be unnecessary and increase the length of my resume.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I list skills on my résumé if I have no interest in using them again?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19625/should-i-list-skills-on-my-r%c3%a9sum%c3%a9-if-i-have-no-interest-in-using-them-again)

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**. You should definitely put C, C++, Java and Python on your resume regardless of which software positions you apply for.

These skillsets will show the hiring managers that, overall, you have a variety of skills, and can learn and adapt quickly to new technologies. In general, these skillsets will always make you a valuable developer.

Furthermore, in more specific cases, the backend legacy code of some companies may still run on C++, Java, and Python, and they will appreciate candidates with these experiences (**especially when you want to be a full-stack developer**).

At the same time, if you want to be a web developer, then also spend more time to learn, practice, master, and then put the **particular web development languages, API, frameworks, and skillsets** on your resume.

Answer (score 3):

A language or framework is only a small part or software development.

There are lots of shared tools and skills between projects of different languages and platforms. Take for example source control (like git) or just requirements gathering. You can be the best programmer there is, if you misunderstand the requirements, the software will fail.

If you have developed software before, even with different languages or frameworks, that is very valuable experience.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been learning C, C++, Java and Python but I want to go into web development

I think you are not aware of what languages are popular for web development.  Both JAVA and Python have extensive web development roots and ecosystems.  So including them in your resume is a reasonable thing to do. However, showing that you can build web applications using these languages would be even better.

As for C and C++, I am not aware of any major frameworks based on these languages (I'm sure there is some masochist out there who will pop up and say "I use C for web development"), but they are good languages to have under your belt. But If you are working in an embedded realm, it is possible that you would be using these languages to construct user interface web pages.

Finally, I'd add C# to the list of languages to look at.  It also has a strong web development ecosystem.

Comment: IIRC ebay was run using C++ originally; but it's been years since the last time I ran across that statement so I assume they've long since migrated to a more conventional stack.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Amazon originally ran C++.  That's what I was writing services in there back in 2005-  it was about 49% C++, 49% Java, 2% other (teams could make their own choices, and you heard rumors of one offs in weird languages.  Although the two above were encouraged and given the most support).